# how to Serialize .Net Class to Avro.Generic.GenericRecord for publishing into kafka topic?

Tags: c#, serialization, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to find a way/helper to convert.Net Class to Avro.Generic.GenericRecord . Currently, I am manually adding field-name and field-value to Generic record. Is there a serializer/converter which I can use to convert the object to generic record and publish on to a kafka topic.

```
class Plant
{
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<PlantProperties> PlantProperties{ get; set; }
}
class PlantProperties
{
 public long Leaves{ get; set; }
 public string Color{ get; set; }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Well a generic record is just a dictionary so you could, serialize your object to an intermediary like JSON and then deserialize to a generic record. JsonConvert should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Confluent Schema Regsitry, you can use their .NET client<sup>1</sup>

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

Copied from the examples folder

```
    using (var serdeProvider = new AvroSerdeProvider(avroConfig))
    using (var producer = new Producer<string, GenericRecord>(producerConfig, serdeProvider.GetSerializerGenerator<string>(), serdeProvider.GetSerializerGenerator<GenericRecord>()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on {topicName}. Enter user names, q to exit.");

        int i = 0;
        string text;
        while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
        {
            var record = new GenericRecord(s);
            record.Add("name", text);
            record.Add("favorite_number", i++);
            record.Add("favorite_color", "blue");

            producer
                .ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, GenericRecord> { Key = text, Value = record })
                .ContinueWith(task => task.IsFaulted
                    ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
                    : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
        }
    }

    cts.Cancel();
}
```

Where, in your case, update the `record.Add` uses accordingly

---

**However**, since you have a class, therefore, you should try to use **SpecificRecord**, rather than serializing back and forth between Avro and a .NET class via a GenericRecord. See the README section on the AvroGen tool for examples of this

<sub>1. I'm not aware of an alternative .NET library</sub>

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 ISpecificRecord solved the issue.

Comment: to avoid writing the avro schema i created my classes first then used AvroSerializer.Create<MyClass>().WriterSchema.ToString() to generate schema, made all the types to have nulls as required, and then used avro_gen.exe tool to regenerate my class properly to implement ISpecific Record.

Comment: Feel free to show those complete steps in a separate answer

Comment: What if your topic can contain multiple event types and you need to identify the type of event during the run time? How to case those into c# model?

Comment: @OlegI A generic record can deserialize any type. If you're asking about specific types, then I think this issue addresses that - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/746

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps I did to solve the problem using the suggestion from @cricket_007.

1. To avoid the complexity of writing the avro schema, create the c# classes first then use AvroSerializer to generate schema.

> AvroSerializer.Create().WriterSchema.ToString()

2. This will generate the schema json for the class. 
   Move it to a schema file and
3. Make all the types to have nulls as Required
4. Then used avro_gen.exe tool to regenerate class files which implements ISpecific Record.
5. Add used the below code to publish to queue

   ```
   using (var serdeProvider = new AvroSerdeProvider(avroConfig))
           using (var producer = new Producer<string, MYClass>(producerConfig, 
     serdeProvider.GetSerializerGenerator<string>(), 
     serdeProvider.GetSerializerGenerator<MYClass>()))
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on 
          {_appSettings.PullListKafka.Topic}.");  

               producer.ProduceAsync(_appSettings.PullListKafka.Topic, new 
   Message<string, MYClass> { Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Value = MYClassObject})
                       .ContinueWith(task => task.IsFaulted
                           ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
                           : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");

           }
   ```

some links to help do this.

https://shanidgafur.github.io/blog/apache-avro-on-dotnet
https://github.com/SidShetye/HelloAvro/tree/master/Avro